# NativeScript iOS Alert Dialog Box Button Color

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Have a funny issue going on and no idea where to start. I have an iOS app that's built with Nativescript & Vue and while in dark mode the button colors in dialogs are off. Sometimes they are a bright blue (which is normal and what I want), but most of the time they are a darker color blue which are really hard to see. Randomly the correct color will show, but mostly the incorrect darker and I can't seem to pattern it out - just random.

The dialog is a `confirm` dialog that is being called in the typical Nativescript Vue manner - nothing custom being called.

Any direction or idea why this may be happening is greatly appreciated.

Incorrect button color

[image: Incorrect button color]

Correct button color

[image: Correct button color]

Note: Dialog message is purposely blacked out

Comment: Are you using nativescript theme plugin?

Comment: @Manoj Yes, using the nativescript core theme

Answer (score 0):

Try writing Button styles at the end of your application level style sheet.

```
Button {
   color: blue; // any color your like
}
```

Unfortunately you can not have separate styles for light / dark mode yet. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3830) you might want to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom model component for alert dialog or https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-fancyalert alert dialog.